# Is there any way to avoid changing URL address bar when using ngview

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

In [this](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView) example the `ng-view` directive doesn´t change the URL in the address bar. But when I port this example to my application the address in the bar changes to the URL in the 'href' link tag on every click, even if I put a relative URL (like the example).

**My html code**

```
<div ng-view></div>

<div class="navHeader">
    <ul id="navItems" ng-controller="Departments">
        <li ng-repeat="department in departments">
            <a href="{{department.url}}">
                {{department.name}}
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**The `href` attribute has been built in the code below:**

```
http.get(SERVICE_ROOT + '/depts').success(function (data) {
  angular.forEach(data, function (value) {
    value.url = SERVICE_ROOT + '/dept/' + value.id; // this line
  });

  model.departments = data;
});
```

Comment: Where is *your* code?

Comment: `In this example ng-view directive don´t change the URL`. Of course it changes, you just can't see it, because it's iframe.

Comment: is there another way to avoid the changing URL address bar?

Comment: You could assign an ng-click function that passes in the department.url and then runs the get function.

Comment: This can't be done cause controller is handled by the routing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no. The point of `ng-view` is to update the template based on the current URL location. It's the SPA equivalent of changing pages.

If you want to do something similar to the example you've linked, then you should look into using `ng-switch`.

**EDIT** updated due to this comment:

> I question this because everytime that anyone does a refresh on the page, it displays only the JSON returned by the service. This happens because the address bar is filled in with the URL for the RESTful service instead of keep the page URL.

The reason this happens is because you are using html pushstate history API (have a google!) AKA `html5mode`. This means to all intents and purposes, you're telling the browser you've loaded a different page, despite actually being not changing page at all. When you hit refresh, the browser requests the url that's in the address bar, which the server responds to, in your case with JSON.

One quick fix is to turn `html5mode` off in your app's `.config` function:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
```

This reverts to using a hash sytax, e.g. *"path.to.your.site/#/about"*. It doesn't look as nice, but it should do the job. Angular will prefix any relative links with the prefix you define.

The **better** option is to modify your server, so that your rest api is under a prefix, e.g. `/api/`, then for all requests that are **not** `/api/*`, you **return your index.html** page. Angular handles the routing after that. This means you have the best of both worlds - your addresses look nicer, (they don't have any #), but refresh etc. works as expected.

Comment: Then is not posible use ng-view and restful service in SPA?

Comment: How did you come to that conclusion? SPAs pretty much rely on a good RESTful API on the backend..

Comment: I mean `ng-view` SPA and RESTful together. I question this because everytime that anyone does a refresh on the page, it displays only the JSON returned by the service. This happens because the address bar is filled in with the URL for the RESTful service instead of keep the page URL. Isn't it so?

Comment: not sure if that can works with jersey, not easy to redirect to index.html on it. My restful service is under localhost:8080/app/service/* and the URL still changes to localhost:8080/app/#/service/, looks very ugly and can´t solve the problem.

Comment: You should be accessing `localhost:8080/app`, and only making **AJAX** requests to `localhost:8080/app/service/*`. Your links should all be relative, which would mean your URL would change to something like:
`localhost:8080/app/#/dept/:id`. I have never used Jersey but you don't want to **redirect** anyway, you should return the index.html **without** redirecting. Any good http server should be able to do that easily.

Comment: If the links with relative path to server can´t perform request on the service how to use ng-view? You can give some fiddle for this working?

Comment: Providing a fiddle to demonstrate this is a lot of work to demonstrate a fundamental angular concept that is documented very well in multiple places. I suggest you google "angular routeProvider" and follow a tutorial.

Comment: I googled "angular routeProvider fiddle" and here's an example that uses it. 

Note that the URL will not change because the displayed page is in an iFrame. It's also using an outdated version of angular but I think the code is still valid.